# Make an image shrink to available height without expanding its parent

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm trying to create a two-column section where:

1. Columns have same width (responsive)
2. The height of block is defined by the height of image contained in left column after it stretches to 100% of it's parent.
3. In the right column there are several elements one of which is a link containing image.

I want that link with image from last paragraph to shrink it's height containing original image aspect ratio without stretching the it's container when the image has portrait orientation.

Not sure it its possible with plain CSS. Tried with flexbox and grid layout but I must be missing something.

I prepared a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kuznets/8u6c70ku/3/

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box }
.wrap { max-width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; }
.container { display: flex; }
.left, .right { 
  flex: 0 0 50%; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.left {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.left div.left-text {
  position: absolute;  
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 200%;
}
.should-set-height {
  width: 100%;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <img class="should-set-height" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x240/aaaaaa/ffffff" alt="">
      <div class="left-text">
        This is a beautiful slogan
      </div>
    </div><!--/.left-->
    <div class="right">
      <header>Product title</header>
      <a class="fit-height" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img class="should-shrink" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x400/aaaaaa/ffffff">
      </a>
      <div class="price">$ 19.99</div>
      <button class="button-black">Add to basket</button>    
    </div><!--/.right-->
  </div><!--/.containter-->
</div><!--/.wrap-->
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could accomplish this would be to have the left image set to have `width: 100%, height: auto;` then use a background image for the right container.

Here's a quick demo on CodePen: https://codepen.io/patriziosotgiu/pen/NaBmZe?editors=1100

You could also add extra rules, like for instance a `min-width` for the left column, or have those columns fit in one column for mobile.

Note: I assumed the left image to be larger than 200x240px

Comment: Thanks for your input. This idea didn't cross my mind. It looks like I will not be able to implement responsiveness (load images of different dimensions for mobile/desktop) without JavaScript. But its an option.

Comment: You're welcome. There may be other ways using breakpoints. Can you give me a few more requirements? What's the largest size for the left image? Is the proportion always going to be the same, or different image size will be used?